# Function update with Service

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 funstions:

```
    public function delete(ArticleRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        return $this->articleService->delete($request->getArticle())
            ? redirect()->back()->with(['success' => __('restaurant.delete.success')])
            : redirect()->back()->with(['error' => __('restaurant.delete.error')]);
    }

    public function update(ArticleStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $article = $this->articleService->update($request->getArticle(), $request->validated(), $request->getImage());

        return !is_null($article)
            ? redirect()->route($this->routesPath . self::SHOW_ACTION, $article->id)->with(['success' => __('update.success')])
            : redirect()->back()->with(['error' => __('update.error')]);
    }

    public function destroy(ArticleRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        return $this->articleService->destroy($request->getArticle())
            ? redirect()->route($this->routesPath . self::INDEX_ACTION)->with(['success' => __('restaurant.destroy.success')])
            : redirect()->back()->with(['error' => __('restaurant.destroy.error')]);
    }
```

`delete` and `destroy` work well. But `update` gives me `'update.error'` when I try to update the image.

But all this funtions are the same as fact.

Why do I have this mistake?

**ArticleService**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Articles;

use App\Helpers\ImageHelper;
use App\Models\Article;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Throwable;

class ArticleService
{
    public function store(array $data, ?UploadedFile $image): ?Article
    {
        try {

            if (!is_null($image)) {
                if ($imageFileName = ImageHelper::save($image, config('app.dish.image.path'))) {
                    $data = array_merge(
                        $data,
                        ['image' => $imageFileName]
                    );
                }
            }

            return Article::create($data);

        } catch (Throwable $ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function update(Article $article, array $data, ?UploadedFile $image): ?Article
    {
        try {

            if (!is_null($image)) {
                if ($imageFileName = ImageHelper::save($image, config('app.dish.image.path'))) {
                    $data = array_merge(
                        $data,
                        ['image' => $imageFileName]
                    );
                }
            }

            $article->update($data);
            return $article;

        } catch (Throwable $ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public function delete(Article $article): bool
    {
        try {

            DB::beginTransaction();
            $article->delete();
            DB::commit();

            return true;
        } catch (Throwable $ex) {

            DB::rollBack();

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function restore(Article $article): bool
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $article->restore();
            DB::commit();

            return true;
        } catch (Throwable $ex) {

            DB::rollBack();

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function destroy(Article $article): bool
    {
        try {

            DB::beginTransaction();
            $article->forceDelete();
            DB::commit();

            return true;
        } catch (Throwable $ex) {

            DB::rollBack();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**upd**

Before I used `update` like:

```
    public function update(ArticleUpdateRequest $request, int $id): RedirectResponse
    {
        $imageData = [
            'image' => ['createThumbs' => false, 'error' => 'error'],
            'preview_image' => ['createThumbs' => false, 'error' => 'error'],
        ];
        return parent::updateModelWithImages($request, $imageData, $request->validated(), $id);
    }
```

But now I don't use `BaseController` where I have `updateModelWithImages`. But how can I get `return` then?

Comment: Whats the return value of article service update method?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Could you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73539983/edit) the code of articleService to your question?

Comment: @shaedrich Do you mean ```update``` or class ```ArticleService``` entirely?

Comment: The entire class

Comment: You are catching all errors and returning null, the issue you have is now invisible. Be careful with catch all error handling as it might cause issues impossible to debug.

Comment: You can either (1) throw the error in your service naturally (= remove the try-catch), (2) do the try-catch in your controller so that you can return `$e->getMessage()` alongside `['error' => __('update.error')]` or at least (3) use `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error()` in your catch in your service

Comment: Check ```upd``` please